# Make a guess about historic events

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, subject-verb-inversion, gre

I am wondering what's the right structure to make a speculation about a past event. I have a GRE writing in which I've put forth a few speculations which could weaken the argument. I've tried to use a conditional structure while sticking to past perfect tense.

> Were they, for example, to build boats using available materials such as bamboo wood or other vegetations, the vehicle would have been rotten and degraded in a few decades, let alone the eons that have been passed until this exploration.

Is this structure acceptable?

Comment: Looks perfect, except I'd go with vegetation (singular). "Had they, for example, _built_ boats..." would work too.

Comment: Also, a boat is more usually a [**vessel**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/vessel) than a [**vehicle**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/vehicle).

Comment: If you're going to use a perfect form at all, you should at least start with it - *Were they, for example, to **have built** boats using available materials...* But the whole text is clumsy and verbose.

Comment: If they are building **boats**, then the **vehicles** would have rotten and degraded. It can only be a single vehicle if they only build one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of grammatical tenses is fine except using *until* with the present perfect. However, there are other problems:

1. *vegetation* is uncountable (see e.g. [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vegetation)) and so it can't be pluralized;
2. *rotten* is an adjective; the past participle of the verb *to rot* is *rotted* (see e.g. [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rot)).
3. *eons* just *pass*; there isn't something else that *passes them.*
4. as far as I understand, *bamboo wood* is a particular manufactured modern material, plywood made of bamboo (see e.g [here](https://www.woodworkerssource.com/bamboo/bamboo-wood-solid-boards-1x12x48-carbonized-dark.html)). What they would have used is thus just *bamboo*, not bamboo wood. (By the way, remember that bamboo is actually a grass, not a tree.)
5. As user Weather Vane pointed out in the comments, we normally don't refer to boats as vehicles. Moreover, as user Jason Bassford pointed out, since it refers to *boats,* whichever word is used here should be pluralized (if countable).

Suggested rewrite:

> Were they, for example, to build boats using available materials such as bamboo or other vegetation, the vessels would have rotted and degraded in a few decades, let alone the eons that passed until this exploration.

This is acceptable, but personally I still don't like the ending. I might prefer something like

> … let alone the eons that have passed since then.

Moreover, depending on what exactly you are trying to say, you may want to a different tense at the beginning, as user FumbleFingers said. As it is, it sounds like they were making a decision based on what would happen to the boats in the centuries after they are built. Presumably, that's not what you actually mean. It is therefore probably better to use one of the following:

> Had they, for example, built boats using… 
>   Were they, for example, to have built boats using…